# Help needed in Tab settings

Tags: tab

i got so much confusion even it is simple one. i am unable to getting exact solution to it. Here is my query.........

Tab settings: default on

Custom Object Permissions: No Access

In this condition, products1 object is not visible on tab bar.

---

Tab settings: default on

Custom Object Permissions: Read only

In this condition, products1 object is visible on tab bar.

i heave given tab setting is default on. if i given default on permission on object it has to visible on tab bar. but Products1 object is not visible if i did not given read only/edit/create/something other than no access to Custom Object Permissions.

Could any one explain me clearly what is the use of tab setting permission along with object permission?

Thanking you

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 2):

When you set up the tab visibility to default on, it would appear on the top bar along with the other tabs, while if you set this to default off, user will be still have access to the tab but he / she will have to click on the + symbol at the end of all tabs and then access it.

If you make the tab hidden, then it will neither be visible at the top bar, and nor by clicking on the + button. However there is a feature available to every user to customize the list of tabs which has to appear once they login as per their preferences.

For a profile you can set the status of tabs as "Default On", "Default Off" and "Tab Hidden"

1. Default On: User with this Tab setting will be able to see the Tab for custom object every time he enters in to the SFDC.
2. Default Off: User with this Tab setting will NOT be able to see the Tab for a custom object when he enters in to SFDC but has the ability to add this tab to his view by customizing the tab view.
3. Tab Hidden: User with this Tab setting will be NOT be able to see the Tab for a custom object and even will NOT be able to bring the tab by customizing the tab view settings.

Comment: Hi Devendra, object is not visible even if i given Default on while Object access permission is No access(I mean unchecked all access). could you explain me this along with object permission........?

Comment: The object (CRUD) permission on profile is at the highest level at the security setting. When you have, read permission on any Object then you can able to view record even though you don't have access to Tab of that Object, as record can be searched from Global Search. When user don't have any permission i.e. No Access on any object then User should not get access to records of that Object, which indirectly hides the Tab of the Object even though you set the Tab accessibility as "Default ON".